# Swift: Class Prefix Needed?

Tags: objective-c, naming-conventions, swift

Should I give my Swift class names a three-letter prefix as recommended by [Objective-C Conventions: Class Names Must Be Unique Across an Entire App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH10-SW4)?

Comment: Now Apple has even gotten rid of the `NS` prefix for classes like `NSNotificationCenter` when used in Swift. However, they still keep the prefix for `NSObject`, which is why we're all having so much fun out here.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

No, [you do not need class prefixes in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/Migration.html), because classes are namespaced to the module in which they live.

If you need to disambiguate between (for example) an `Array` from Swift and an `Array` class/struct that you've declared in your app, you can do so by typing it as a `Swift.Array` or a `MyProject.Array`. That works with extensions as well:

```
extension Swift.Array {
    ...
}

extension MyProject.Array {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this carry over if you import into objective c?

Comment: @Jeef [This Stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26148391/2067021) seems to indicate that there can be naming collisions when classes are imported into Objective-C.

Comment: Since you choose class names on export with `@objc` tag, I think you're supposed to do both, so in Swift `SimpleAlert` becomes `DRSimpleAlert`

Answer (score 18):

**No, prefix is definitely not neeeded.**

Suppose your app has `MyApp` name, and you need to declare your custom `UICollectionViewController`.

You **don't need** to prefix and subclass like this:

```
class MAUICollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {}
```

Do it like this:

```
class UICollectionViewController {} //no error "invalid redeclaration o..."
```

**Why?**. Because what you've declared is declared in **current module**, which is your **current target**. And `UICollectionViewController` from `UIKit` is declared in `UIKit` module.

**How to use it within current module?**

```
var customController = UICollectionViewController() //your custom class
var uikitController = UIKit.UICollectionViewController() //class from UIKit
```

**How to distinguish them from another module?**

```
var customController = MyApp.UICollectionViewController() //your custom class
var uikitController = UIKit.UICollectionViewController() //class from UIKit
```

Comment: How does this work with Objective-C? For example, if an instance of this Swift subclass is to be created in ObjC, you'd be calling: [UIViewController alloc] init].