# Prefix extension functions

Tags: ios, macos, swift, naming-conventions

In Swift it's not necessary to [prefix classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214863/swift-class-prefix-needed) anymore as their module acts as the namespace.

What about prefixing extension functions? For example:

```
extension UIImage {

    public func hnk_hasAlpha() -> Bool { ... }

}
```

On one hand Swift is not dynamic so collisions would generate compiler errors.

But what happens if compiled code runs in a future iOS/OS X version in which one of my extension methods is added? Would methods in different modules be considered different symbols even if they have the same signature?

Does it make a difference if the extended class is a NSObject subclass or a pure Swift class?

Comment: Why do you think it is a good idea to add functionality to an Apple supplied class? Why not just write a function. That would be clear to future developers working with the code. Or subclass.

Comment: Whether it's a good idea or not is irrelevant from the technical aspect of the question, which is how does Swift handle this kind of collisions. That said, I do think extending Apple classes is useful to give functions better context while limiting the scope of the symbol, and to implement custom protocols without resorting to wrapper objects, among other things.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's some subtlety here:

Extensions of Objective-C types are implemented as Objective-C categories, with all that implies.

Extensions of Swift types, however, are only in effect where visible due to imports. This means that you can't accidentally stomp on a private system method (whether now or one introduced in the future), and if the system introduces a public method with the same name as yours, you'll get a compile-time failure when you rebuild, but your existing app won't break.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a source?

Comment: Don't remember, tbh. Some combination of dev forums and talking to people working on swift.

Comment: @hpique Check this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35 section 'Extensions'. 
Last statement states 'You cannot use extensions to override existing methods or properties on Objective-C types.'

Compiler returns an error if finds conflicting signatures.

Comment: OK, so then when (if ever) should I prefix extension methods? Specifically, should I prefix a public instance method that I've added to `NSHTTPURLResponse` (via an extension) in my Swift framework? I see that [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) prefixes its public `NSHTTPURLResponse` extension methods and [SnapKit](http://snapkit.io) prefixes its public `UIView` extension methods. Why?

Comment: I think I found out why: [iOS Developer Library: Programming with Objective-C: Avoid Category Method Name Clashes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW4).

Answer (score 1):

You should check those threads also:

[Name collisions for extension methods from different frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892897/name-collisions-for-extension-methods-from-different-frameworks) - quote from thread:

> regardless the application code imports which Framework, it seems, the actual called implementation depends on the order in Linked Frameworks and Libraries in "First come, first served" manner. But, as far as I know, this behavior is not guaranteed.

and [Swift Extension: same extension function in two Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736698/swift-extension-same-extension-function-in-two-modules/) which also confirms the same problem.

So based on that for Objective-C objects such as UIImage from your example name collisions are possible and you might see unexpected behaviour if there will be two methods with the same name in two different extensions for Objective-C object.