# Name collisions for extension methods from different frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, namespaces, swift-extensions

As a test, I created two frameworks.  Both frameworks contain this extension:

```
public extension UIDevice {
    var extraInfo: UIDeviceExtraInfo {
        return UIDeviceExtraInfo()
    }
}

public class UIDeviceExtraInfo {
    public var prop: String = "Device1"  //"Device2" is used in another framework
}
```

I then imported the two frameworks and attempt to print `UIDevice.currentDevice().extraInfo.prop`.  Swift compiler gives the error: `Ambiguous use of extraInfo"`.

How does one go about resolving name clashing like this?

Comment: Essentially the same question (without answer) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736698/swift-extension-same-extension-function-in-two-modules. I assume that there is no solution.

Comment: is there a solution now 3 years later?

Answer (score 7):

In this specific case, you can disambiguate `extraInfo` prop by explicilty specifying expected type:

```
import FW1
import FW2

let fw1Info = UIDevice.currentDevice().extraInfo as FW1.UIDeviceExtraInfo
let fw2Info = UIDevice.currentDevice().extraInfo as FW2.UIDeviceExtraInfo
print(fw1Info.prop) // -> Device1
print(fw2Info.prop) // -> Device2
```

But, when the method/prop return the same type:

```
// FW1
public extension UIDevice {
    var myInfo: String { return "Device1" }
}

// FW2
public extension UIDevice {
    var myInfo: String { return "Device2" }
}

// App
import FW1

print(UIDevice.currentDevice().myInfo) // -> ???
```

There is no way to disambiguate them. And regardless the application code imports which Framework, *it seems*, the actual called implementation depends on the order in **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** in "First come, first served" manner. But, as far as I know, this behavior is not guaranteed.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I *think* I had also the case where one method from FW1 and another method from FW2 was called, but I am not sure. – Extensions for NSObject subclasses are Objective-C categories, and defining the same method in different ObjC categories is undefined behaviour. As mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736698/swift-extension-same-extension-function-in-two-modules, the behaviour *might* be different for "pure" Swift extensions.

Comment: Actually the case of just importing FW1 in the app works.  Console prints Device1 in my test.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of experimentation, the only way I've found is to only import one of the frameworks into your source file.

Comment: That makes it compile, but does not guarantee that the method from the imported framework is used. See the example at the end of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32736698/1187415.

Comment: It worked fine in the little unit test I did, but I chose to add the extensions to  `String`, which is a struct and that might have helped disambiguate the calls at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on a project where I have CryptoSwift and after that I was already "compiled" a propietary framework without source code only header files.

So in this moment you have 3 options:

1. Ask the providers to change their names
2. Modify one of them (in this case crypto swift because it is open source and you can modify the name of the extensions, obviously not only in your code that calls it, but in the cloned dependency... which is a hasle if you need to upgrade dependencies)
3. Change the name you call it so there is no error and know the internal you want to use, I did make an extension in this case of Data and copied what CryptoSwift did to my own file where the collision existed (so it take a local definition of the code):

```
extension Data {
    public var myBytes: Array<UInt8> {
        return Array(self)
    }
}
```

See that now I have to change all the calls of my code to myBytes and that I have the source code to implement this call, so no more collisions even if you cant do 1 or 2 (because to much hasle). If you cant do any of the 3, I guess there is no solution.

BY the way, it is unfortunate that swift doesn't support a way to disambiguate this on the language itself.