# Do Swift Models translate to Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift

The answer to this questions ([Swift: Class Prefix Needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214863/swift-class-prefix-needed/24214975#24214975)) says in swift there is no need to deconflict Swift Moduels (frameworks) that have classes with the same name because you can use a `Module.Class` name scheme such as:

```
let a1 : Module1.Array 
let a2 : Moduel2.Array
```

to deal with any conflicts you might run into.

Well thats nice and all, but what happens when we import one of these models into Objective C.

I know you can use the `@objc(NAME)` directive to give your class a different name in ObjC, but I was wondering if there was some way to get a similar namespacing construct to work.  I've tried both `@import Module` and `#import <Module/Module-Swift.h>` but I have yet to come up with a way to be able to refer to things in the C++ equivalent of a namespace.

Am I missing something or is this not possible

Comment: Objective-C has no namespaces. It's all one giant namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. You need to give the classes separate Objective-C names using `@objc`.