# Object Naming Conventions

Tags: ios, swift

I have specific question about Apple naming convetions... I'm confused about how should I name my generic custom cells, buttons, views ... etc. (like for example should I name my cell with 3 labels and a button for example like:

```
(ProjectName)LeftTitleTwoSubtitlesRightButtonCell
```

or there is a better solution / convention for it ... Or if there is any article ( I'm specifically searching for naming objects like buttons / cells / views ... that are generic)

Comment: Most class names are prefixed by a 2- or 3-letter abbreviation suggesting the project or company name. For example, `NSString` is named for "**N**eXT**S**TEP String"

Comment: Rather than describing the cell in the name, what is the cell used (or usable) for...

Comment: it's a generic cell for whole project ... it's meant to be reused ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes the class names are prefixed with 2-3 characters suggesting the project name.
Also the class name follows pascal case , methods follows camel case & variables follow camel case.
While naming labels and buttons try to give them a readable & informative name suffixed with Lbl or Btn for label & button respectively. 
Also you can refer following links to improve coding standards.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html
http://www.futureworkshops.com/articles/naming-conventions.html

Comment: Your references are for Objective-C. Compare [Swift: Class Prefix Needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214863/swift-class-prefix-needed).

Comment: Correct, for Swift, 2-3 character prefixes are neither needed nor recommended. Furthermore, Apple advises clarity over brevity, so you'd want to use suffixes like `Label` and `Button`, not `Lbl` and `Btn`. I'm pretty sure there was a WWDC video that touched upon these stylistic issues, but it's eluding me right now, but it's out there.