# How to add a prefix to a lot of existing swift files and classes in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, refactoring, rename

**I'm working on a project and I created a lot of swift classes**. As you know with swift you do not need to add a prefix in front of the class or file name; and so I didn't.

**Now I was required to add a prefix to them** (let's say "KK" in front of each file and class)

I was wandering if **someone managed to do this with a single command**, I would like to avoid renaming and refactoring each class one by one.

*example:*

*a file called FridgeView.swift containing a class FridgeView
should be renamed KKFridgeView.swift and the class KKFridgeView*

*P.S. I know we do not need prefix in swift but it is a requirement of my company I really have no choice :)*

Comment: You don't need prefixes in swift and it's no opportunity to do it. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24214975/5397625

Comment: Try this tool (I just googled, didn't try it myself) https://github.com/kyle-fox/rename-xcode-files

Comment: @AntonRodick I know, it is written in the question

Comment: @BencePattogato thanks for the link, if there is no other option I will use it :) , it would be annoying to manually add each class to rename to the txt but it is better than nothing :D

Answer (score 1):

Step One Click the Project Name

[image: ![Project Name]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFQKE.png)

Then you can find Class Prefix on you right Side

[image: This Image]

Add your prefix and then Create all you `viewController` and `Class`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vicky. The problem is that I already create tons of classes without prefix and I have to rename them

Comment: @AlbertoScampini Do u find any solution for ur comments ? Now am in that situation.,., Can help me on this ?

Comment: @McDonal_11 honestly I can't remember, but I don't think so. I remember looking for a python script at some point.

Comment: Np., Thanks for ur reply @AlbertoScampini

Answer (score 0):

It can be set from file inspection menu but it will only new files added into project. it will not impact already added files.

[image]